# Execute two commands with wait in linux

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I want to write a script which executes the following commands:

```
./virtuoso-t -f -c /home/var/lib/virtuoso/db/virtuoso.ini
```

which gives the following output -- after "Server online at 1111" appears on screen I want to issue another command ./isql 1111 dba dba. I dont want to issue the command "./isql 1111 dba dba" before "Server online at 1111" appears on screen -- the command ./isql 1111 dba dba should be issued in different session (screen, etc) as I want ./virtuoso-t to remain online while I execute my commands -- is there some way by which I may achieve the same

```
        Mon Aug 03 2015
17:08:49 { Loading plugin 1: Type `plain', file `wikiv' in `/home/jyotil/VirtuosoHugh/virtuosoInstalled/lib/virtuoso/hosting'
17:08:49   FAILED  plugin 1: Unable to locate file }
17:08:49 { Loading plugin 2: Type `plain', file `mediawiki' in `/home/jyotil/VirtuosoHugh/virtuosoInstalled/lib/virtuoso/hosting'
17:08:49   FAILED  plugin 2: Unable to locate file }
17:08:49 { Loading plugin 3: Type `plain', file `creolewiki' in `/home/jyotil/VirtuosoHugh/virtuosoInstalled/lib/virtuoso/hosting'
17:08:49   FAILED  plugin 3: Unable to locate file }
17:08:49 OpenLink Virtuoso Universal Server
17:08:49 Version 07.20.3213-pthreads for Linux as of Apr 10 2015
17:08:49 uses parts of OpenSSL, PCRE, Html Tidy
17:08:59 Database version 3126
17:09:00 SQL Optimizer enabled (max 1000 layouts)
17:09:01 Compiler unit is timed at 0.000687 msec
17:09:38 Roll forward started
17:09:38 Roll forward complete
17:09:52 Checkpoint started
17:09:54 Checkpoint finished, log reused
17:09:57 HTTP/WebDAV server online at 8890
17:09:57 Server online at 1111 (pid 4972)
```

For doing so I wrote the following shell script in (myScript.sh):

```
./virtuoso-t -f -c /home/var/lib/virtuoso/db/virtuoso.ini
./isql 1111 dba dba
```

However it appears that ./isql 1111 dba dba gets executed before "Server online at 1111" appears on screen. Is there some way in either python (by invoking the commands from python or c++ or using linux commands with which I may achieve the desired behaviour?

The command "./virtuoso-t -f -c /home/var/lib/virtuoso/db/virtuoso.ini" does not terminate, it remains online with the output "Server online at 1111" and in another terminal I execute queries on it using ./isql 1111 dba dba

Answer (score 2):

You need sequential commands. To achieve this, concatenate your commands with `;`, like this:

```
 sleep 5s ; ls
```

You will notice that the directory listing happens after `sleep` finishes.

To match your specific example, run:

```
./virtuoso-t -f -c /home/var/lib/virtuoso/db/virtuoso.ini ; ./isql 1111 dba dba
```

To test if your server has started, adapt the following code to what you need. It uses `netstat` to check for opened ports on the host:

```
while netstat -lnt | awk '$4 ~ /:3306$/ {print "running"; system("ls"); exit 1}'; do sleep 2s; done
```

Note: i'm listening for a mysql server (3306 port - you need 1111)
Replace `system("ls")` with `system("sh /full/path/to script")`
`print "running";` is optional (just textual status)

Comment: or better, `command1 && command2`, so that the `command2` won't be executed if `command1` fails.

Comment: @fedorqui, good point, but as far as I know, `&&` takes into account the returned value from the first command. And some of them also return 0 in case of success. This needs proper analysis. For a general "wait 'till first finished", i think `;` does the trick

Comment: Thanks but my problem is the first command does not terminate..it remains there with the output "Server online at 1111 " and I execute "./isql 1111 dba dba" in another terminal..

Comment: I mean ./virtuoso-t starts a server..which is a database engine..it remains online with the output "Server online at 1111" on screen and using ./isql I can execute queries on this server...now I want to keep the server online in my script and issue queries using the command ./isql 1111 dba dba

Comment: @JannatArora, Using this updated answer, I was able to successfully wait for mysql to start, then run "ls" in the current directory. I think this suites your case.

Answer (score 2):

You could reasonably wait until the line appears, by sending output to a file and grepping ...

```
#!/bin/bash
./virtuoso-t -f -c /home/var/lib/virtuoso/db/virtuoso.ini > log 2>&1 &
PID=$!
while [[ -d /proc/$PID && ! grep -q -m 1 "Server online at" log ]];
do
  sleep 1;
done
./isql 1111 dba dba
```

This:

1. runs the server as a background process (`&`) and redirects its output to a file
2. loops until the server emits the desired message to that file
3. checks the server is alive, so a failed startup doesn't cause an infinite wait.

---

Edit:

Bash supports both the [new](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_005d_005d) `[[ ... ]]` and [old](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-test) `[ ... ]` conditional forms. The newer is preferred, but if your shell doesn't support it, try the old one.

It's possible your `/bin/bash` isn't really bash, I suppose, try running `/bin/bash --version` to see. If it's a simpler shell, `#!/usr/bin/bash` might work.

Comment: Thanks..what does -d /proc/$PID  do.. also why are we looking in log when the output is appearing on screen

Comment: ok..do we get the process id of the background process using PID=$! .. if not then what does it so...also we are we using -d /proc/$PID

Comment: Also when I execute this I am getting " [[: not found"

Comment: Yes my shell is bash i checked using echo $0 it gave /bin/bash. But I dont know why am I getting [[: not found. I did save the script using the same first line

Comment: should i use...while // -d /proc/$PID && ! grep -q -m 1 "Server online at" log //;

Comment: I'm suggesting that you use `if [ -d ... ]; then`, ie, use the old `[` form instead of the newer `[[` form that doesn't seem to work for you. These comments aren't spacious enough to learn shell scripting though - I recommend that you learn to use the online manual, and of course ask more questions (as new questions) as they arise.

Comment: sorry for my insufficient knowledge..so should I use: while [ -d /proc/$PID && ! grep -q -m 1 "Server online at" log ];

Answer (score 2):

I came up with this, it reads the piped output line by line until it finds the one you are looking for.

```
#!/bin/bash

virtuoso-t -f -c /home/var/lib/virtuoso/db/virtuoso.ini 2>&1 | while read line
do
    echo $line
    if echo $line|grep 'Server online at 1111' > /dev/null; then
        isql 1111 dba dba
    fi
done
```